# Are things any better in what society considers "third world countries" as they were years ago? If things are better, how did they improve and why?

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, money, political-economy, poverty

For years I've seen non-stop commercials of countries in the continent of Africa showing kids who live in sewage huts, parents are dead, war gangs and criminals rule their lives.  Like in Captain Philips how those Somalia pirates were forced to do what they did because of where they lived. They were forced by criminals threatening their lives.  Didn't the USA make their countries dry out and collapsed like many Middle Eastern ones?

My professor showed a video made in Africa showing how 1 in 3 Africans are actually middle class.  They have cells, cities, even women Presidents at times.  So are things than better than in the past and if so why?

Comment: If you are hoping to get an intelligent and non-opinionated answer you'll have to specify how you measure "better". (E.g.: per capita GDP, Gini-index, infant mortality ratio.) And as you seem to find it possible that 1 in 3 Africans are middle class, perhaps you could include a definition of middle class as well? (Wikipedia gives conflicting data: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_class#Africa )

Comment: "Third world" is not a very useful definition these days. There's a huge difference between a "Least developed country" and a "Newly industrialised country"

Comment: @denesp every time I ask something I get that it too opinionated.  What am I doing wrong?  What can I ask without being spoken down to or reported?

Comment: Listen truth is this.....I'm young.  I'm 22, I work, I graduate college soon, and I save what I can.  But I'm terrified.  All I hear from my older suntan and uncles and adults way older that this country is going to crap.  There going to be no jobs, generations are becoming too spoiled and selfish, people lose jobs to robots and what if they let us starve and not care some can't find work.  Not just America but Europe too.  Cause Africa to me seems like it getting worse personally so the rest of Earth is too.

Comment: .....I'm scared for me and my little cousins and I have one cousin who just turned 1.  What future will she have at least I got college.  By the time she my age it will cost so much what will she do?  What will the world look like?  I'm scared.  If someone can tell me it won't get that bad that greed won't win and robots won't take most jobs and leave enough left and hard work well be ok...that we won't freeze and starve on the street...I'll stop.  That's it

Comment: @Bruno1993 is the number 5 better than the color red? If you can answer this then your question without a measure may also be answered. Do you see the problem? I would also like to apologize if I offended you, it was not my intention. But you really have to clarify if you want a good answer.

Comment: @denesp I will stop stop asking the same question different ways if you can just give me even a moderate knowing answer: Is everyone who is not rich like every little baby of a poor family doomed to only have their lives get worse?  Because of the bad governments and destroyed economy?  Overall, are we going to turn into an underdeveloped looking nation like Zimbawea (by "we" I mean America! Canada and Europe, even China cause they're polluted as heck how will they possibly get better?

Comment: That all...are we doomed? Is the future pointless?

Comment: No it isn't. I hope you are satisfied with my opinion based answer but I have a feeling you won't be.

Comment: @Bruno1993 Might be a bit late... but would highly recommend [this book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0756J1LLV)